# JQuery UI position with dialog

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with positioning a dialog with JQuety UI.

I'm using the code

```
var divObj = $('#sourceCodeSearchDialog');
divObj.dialog(
    {
        position: ['right-800 top-100']
    });
```

but no matter how small I make the top value the dialog doesn't appear any further up the page.

The link that is calling it is quite far down the page so it might be that it is drawing the dialog at the top of the screen (not the page). When the focus is set on the text box in the dialog, the screen is scrolled to focus on the text box. However because the dialog isn't at the top of the page, not all the dialog box is visible.

I know a work around is to scroll the page but this makes the process quite "jumpy" as it display the dialog and then scrolls.

Comment: Can you please add up some fiddle or something to see whats happening ??

Comment: One example can be `position: {my: "center", at: "center", of: window.top},`

Comment: If I move the calling link further up the page then I can position the dialog OK. It really looks like I can only draw the dialog in the window that is being displayed and not anywhere on the page.

Comment: position: {my: "center", at: "center", of: window.top},

Seems to display it in the center of the window before the focus changes. So the dialog appears off the screen (the page scrolls to the top but the dialog box is in the center of the page which is below the bottom of the part of the page you can see).

Comment: The code that calls the dialog is below, could this be what is causing the page to scroll to the top?
         <a href="#" onclick="popUpSourceCodeSearchWindow('Search Source Codes', 'SourceCode', 'SourceCodeText', 'onBehalfOfGroupName','','#SourceCodeSearchResults');">Search all source codes</a>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var divObj = $('#sourceCodeSearchDialog');
divObj.dialog({ 
  // other setting if u want like `modal : true` etc
}, 'position', [800,100]);
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. Even changing the 800,100 numbers to 1,1 didn't make any difference to the positioning of the dialog which wasn't what I was expecting at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you are expecting, but try this:

```
var divObj = $('#sourceCodeSearchDialog');
divObj.dialog(
{
    position: {my: "right-800, top-100", at: "center", of: window}
});
```

Comment: That didn't work either, it displayed the dialog box lower down the page.
If I changed the top to top-10000 then it moves it to where my code put it. I still think I should be referencing the page rather than the window, any thoughts?

Comment: @EdenUK See if changing at: "center" to at: "top center" works. And, if you want to refer the page rather than the window, replace of: window with of: document

Comment: I was so excited when I saw the document option, but sadly it behaved in the same way, with the dialog appear half way down the screen. Is there a list of all the different "of:" options? http://api.jqueryui.com/position/ was a bit vague probably due to the number of possibilities.

Comment: @EdenUK its just similar to JavaScript selectors. document, window or even "#targetElement" the #targetElement is used to position your element in this context with respect to another element in the page. Like a textbox or a div. Replce #targetElement with the element you would want your element to position itself in accordance with.